# When use H1, H2, H3, H4, H5 tags?

Tags: html, css

My question is Suppose we have some text like "Enjoy the day with us" and its having font-size, font-weight,line-height same as H2 tag, but this text is not a heading or subheading text. 
So now my question is for this text what should we use? If we use H2 tag then we need to write only font-family and if we use P tag then we need to apply all these property like 
font-size, font-weight, line-height and font-family.

What is the standard practices for this scenario?

Answer (score 10):

> What is the standard practices for this scenario?

Using the tags isn't about *presentation*, it's about [*semantics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics). If you use the various `h1`, `h2`, etc. tags, you're giving information about the *meaning* of the content of the text within them. This gives anything reading your document information about the document's structure and meaning. There's a [section about the semantics of headings and sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections) in the spec.

The following markup tells software reading it that the text "Web Semantics" is a heading for content in the document, and therefore that the following paragraphs likely relate to web semantics:

```
<h1>Web Semantics</h1>
<p>Blah blah blah blah</p>
```

In contrast, if you have this:

```
<div>Web Semantics</div>
<p>Blah blah blah blah</p>
```

then even if the `div` is styled to look just like an `h1`, there's no information in your document about the *meaning* of the text "web semantics" (in the context of your document).

This matters for content extraction, including the ever-popular SEO.

Answer (score 4):

`<h1>` `<h2>` etc tags should be used to indicate that a block of text is a heading.

It should not *necessarily* be used to make text bold, larger etc. However typically a heading will have more prominent (e.g. bolder, larger) text the text (e.g. `<p>`) it is heading.

Heading should also be hierarchical e.g.

```
<h1>Main heading</h1>
<p>Introduction text</p>
<h2>Section</h2>
<p>Further text</p>
<h3>Sub section</h3>
<p>Further text</p>
<h2>A new section</h2>
<p>New sections text</p>
```

etc

The [BBC have some good guidance on semantic use of headings](http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidelines/futuremedia/technical/semantic_markup.shtml#headings).

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume anyting about the styling of any H element. The browser only applies some default styling in case your page doesn't specify it. But the elements mainly have a *semantic* value.

The `<Hx>` elements are for headers. If your text is a paragraph rather than a header, use `<P>`.

Most webpages nowadays reset most of the default styling of elements to introduce their own styling. And that's fine. So, why not use `<P>` for anything? Like I said, using specific elements gives a semantic structure to the document, and that allows it to be easily readable by search engines and screen readers (reading aides for visually impaired).

If you want to change the looks of things, use CSS and don't rely on the default style the browser gives an element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is very generalized question. There are many ways to decide when to use which heading tag...

Some of the most commonly followed reasons are :

1. Structuring the content - heading make it look prominent.
2. SEO - yes, SEO Optimizations are heavily dependent on how you make titles of your articles attractive..

Some links you might want to follow :

http://www.kenkai.com/seo-blog-article-249.htm

http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

Answer (score 0):

Your markup should be semantic, so you should use the proper element for the content in question. If it's not a heading, don't use a heading tag. Better to use a p or some other tag. For ease of use you could attach a class to it if this style gets repeated often.

Answer (score 0):

When using HTML headings it is making sure your code is semantically correct. This is the main reason H1 is the largest (if you have no styling) because that's the main "heading" for your page. H2 is for something relating to your page but is not the main page title (such as an article) but it is less important.

`<h1>News Page</h1>
 <h2>StackOverflow Is Awesome</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
 <h2>StackOverflow Is Even More Awesome</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>`